# T(n) in big O notation

Tags: python, big-o

When calculating [T(n)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) complexity is 1n usually represented as just n?

For example in the following Python code:

```
def Average(aList):
    x = len(aList)
    total = 0
    for item in aList:
        total = total + item
    mean = total / n
    return mean
```

Now working out T(n) the function starts with 2 assignments, 1 loop which is 1n assignments and 1 assignment after the loop giving

T(n) = 1n + 3

would the 1 be dropped giving n+3 giving O(n)?

Comment: Your function is `0(n)` , is that what you are asking? Whether it is 3n 5n 10n it is still 0(n)

Comment: No do i drop the 1n and class it as just n?

Comment: Yes,  the 1 is irrelevant, the running time is linear

Comment: Im not fussed about the Big o. But when working out the T(n) will it be 1n+3 or just simply n+3

Comment: In most algebraic notations, `1n` is equivalent to `n`.

Comment: @dimo414 that's what I assumed. Its just revision i am doing and in the answer the 1 in 1n has been dropped. The other possible answers are:-                            T(n) = 2n+2,                        T(n) = 3+n^2,                         T(n) = n+2,             T(n) = 3n +n^2,                   T(n) = n +3

Answer (score 3):

Order notation is about the *growth* of algorithmic complexity, not about the specific number of operations.

So, O(3n) grows as the same *rate* as O(n), so the multiplicative and additive constants are eliminated.  Think about ratios, if you double the value of "n", then in both cases, the timings double.

Slower growing components are ignored.  In the limit O(n + 3) grows at about the same rate at O(n).  For that matter, it grows at about the same rate as O(10n + log(n) + 7).

The key idea in order notation is what happens as "n" grows.  It is not about counting all the specific operations.

Answer (score 2):

"Big O" (or Landau) notation all constants are dropped because they do not influence the growth of a function/complexity. Therefore 1n + 3 would be O(n) and not O(1n+3) or O(n+3).

This is because of the linearity of that function. Something like 2n would be O(n) also, because the factor 2 just factorizes the output of the function but does not affect the "intensity/rate" at which your function grows.

Answer (score 1):

It's the ["Big O" notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Addition of constants drops out, as well as does the multiplication by a constant.

[image: The Big O]